# Matlab table Function, why isn't it showing my full table?

Tags: matlab

Very basic question here. So, I'm publishing a table in matlab and have an issue. Here is how I am doing the table:

```
t = 0:.1:16;
B = a function of t...
G = also a function of t...
```

the functions work perfectly and the result is all correct. I have graphed to confirm that things are what they should be. However, when I go to create a table, showing only the integer values of t and the respective values of G and B at these points with:

```
T = table(t(1:10:161), B(1:10:161), G(1:10:161))
```

my output looks like this:

```
ans = 

        Var1             Var2             Var3     
    _____________    _____________    _____________

    [1x17 double]    [1x17 double]    [1x17 double]
```

Why is matlab doing this/how can I show the values instead of having them show as [1x17 double]? There is very little support for the table function offered by mathworks, as I am doing exactly what it says to do on the website and am not getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB have decided that this is ugly. I do not think that you can do so much about it. Also, each column would indeed get fairly wide. Try

```
`fprintf('%f    ',t(1:10:161), B(1:10:161), G(1:10:161) ); fprintf('\n')`.
```

However, to get the printouts, try to use column vectors

```
T = table(t(1:10:161).', B(1:10:161).', G(1:10:161).')
```

Where `.'` is used instead of `'` since `'` means hermitian transpose (or conjugate transpose).

It may be good to note here that MATLAB store the matrices columnwise, so column vectors should always be used (as in linear algrbra) if possible.